# Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (OkHttp)

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I am trying to get web server response with OkHttp.
My current  `minSdkVersion 15`.

My code is

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        GetDataFromUrl getData = new GetDataFromUrl();
        String response = null;
        try {
                response = getData.run(URL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

And

```
String run(String url) throws IOException {
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
```

I am getting a warning at the line `try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute())`.

It's saying "`Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 15)`.

I know that if I change the minimum API level to 19, it'll work fine. But I have to support min 15 API level.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to not use try-with-resources unless you can set your min API level to 19. So instead of this:

```
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
}
```

you should to this:

```
Response response = null;
try {
    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
} finally {
    if (response != null) {
        response.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: The [Java Language Specification, Section 14.20.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) provides a slightly different (but, in this case, functionally identical) equivalent to a basic try-with-resources statement (one without any `catch` or `finally` blocks) like you have:

```
{
    final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    Throwable primaryExc = null;

    try {
        return response.body().string();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        primaryExc = t;
        throw t;
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            if (primaryExc != null) {
                try {
                    response.close();
                } catch (Throwable suppressed) {
                    primaryExc.addSuppressed(suppressed);
                }
            } else {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has two effects. First, it makes the `response` variable local to the equivalent block. (My suggestion made it visible after the `try` statement finishes, which may be undesirable.) More importantly, it has the effect of suppressing any exception thrown while closing the resource. That is, if the body of the original `try` block throws an exception, invoking code will see that instead of the exception thrown by the `close()`. (The exception thrown by the `close()` would still be available via the `getSuppressed()` method of the exception actually thrown.) You don't need this more complicated version because (as far as I can tell from the API docs) `Response.close()` doesn't throw exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

For future reader.

Now, that there is Java 8. You just have to specify to compile with Java 8 in gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

The warning will go away. Compiler will translate the code to what Ted Hopp in the answer.