# Android Studio 3.0: Try-with-resources requires API level 19

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

```
Android Studio 3.0

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

In official documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features

I read the following:

> "In addition to the Java 8 language features and APIs above, Android
> Studio 3.0 and later extends support for try-with-resources to all
> Android API levels."

OK.
And here my snippet:

```
public static boolean writeToDir(File path, String fileName, InputStream inputStream) {
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, fileName))) {
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

And I get compile error:

```
Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 15)
```

Why?

In official documentation is written:

> "... try-with-resources to ALL Android API levels"

Comment: Maybe limited to "Java 8 language features and APIs above" and FileOutputStream (a child class of java.io.OutputStream) is not a part of them, I guess, and AutoCloseable is from API19.

Comment: from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html. So java.io.FileOutputStream implements AutoCloseable

Comment: java.util.stream is listed in Java 8 Language API, but java.io.OutputStream is not. AutoCloseable  is for "requires API level 19" part.

Comment: See the answer in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408628/try-with-resources-requires-api-level-19-okhttp/49615729#49615729