# Java code in Android Studio to delete a file or erase data in it

Tags: java, android, text-files, delete-file

I tried different codes but none seem to work. The deletion is going into the same directory. It can detect the file. It also gives false positive as deleted but when the file is prompted to be opened the text in the files opens without any problem. Is it that the file is not deleted or is that the file is saved in the memory? It is OK if not deleting the file. I just want to delete the content inside it, it is a text file.

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```java
File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, n);
deleteFile(n);
```

I tried this code earlier to erase data, or modify it, but it's not working either:

```java
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(name1, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(save.getBytes());
    Toast.makeText(Home2.this,
                   "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + name1,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to completely erase all text in it and delete the file if possible.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I wanted to completely erase all text in it and delete the file if possible._ What exactly do you mean by _erase all text in it_? Do you want to make it an empty file before you delete it? Why would you need to do that if you are going to delete the file anyway?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: If possible, I recommend that you use [try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314061/android-studio-3-0-try-with-resources-requires-api-level-19)

Answer (score 0):

This code will open the file, erase its content, and then delete the file if needed:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

// ...

// Define the file name
String fileName = "your_text_file.txt";

// Get the file object
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

try {
    // Open the file for writing, this will erase its content
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    // Optionally, delete the file after erasing its content
    boolean deleteFileAfterErase = true;

    // If you want to delete the file, uncomment the next line
    // deleteFileAfterErase = file.delete();

    writer.close();

    if (deleteFileAfterErase) {
        // The file is deleted after erasing its content
        Toast.makeText(Home2.this, "File content erased and deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // The file content is erased, but the file is not deleted
        Toast.makeText(Home2.this, "File content erased.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(Home2.this, "Error erasing file content.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This code first opens the file in write mode, erasing the contents of the file. You can then choose whether to delete the file after clearing the contents by setting the `deleteFileAfterErase` variable to true or false.

If you set `deleteFileAfterErase` to true, the contents of the file are deleted, and if you set it to false, only the contents are deleted and the empty file remains.